# Python list comprehension to create unequal length lists from a list using conditional

Tags: python, generator, list-comprehension

Using list comprehension, `itertools` or similar functions, is it possible to create two unequal lists from one list based on a conditional? Here is an example:

```py
main_list = [6, 3, 4, 0, 9, 1]
part_list = [4, 5, 1, 2, 7]

in_main = []
out_main = []

for p in part_list:
    if p not in main_list:
        out_main.append(p)
    else:
        in_main.append(p)

>>> out_main
[5, 2, 7]

>>> in_main
[4, 1]
```

I'm trying to keep it simple, but as an example of usage, the `main_list` could be values from a dictionary with the `part_list` containing dictionary keys.  I need to generate both lists at the same time.

Comment: I feel this could be done with sets

Comment: @JakobBowyer main_list values could be generated from a dictionary.  sets is the obvious solution but looking for a single list comprehension or itertools type solution that is generating both lists at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A true `itertools`-based solution that works on an iterable:

```
>>> part_iter = iter(part_list)
>>> part_in, part_out = itertools.tee(part_iter)
>>> in_main = (p for p in part_in if p in main_list)
>>> out_main = (p for p in part_out if p not in main_list)
```

Making lists out of these defeats the point of using iterators, but here is the result:

```
>>> list(in_main)
[4, 1]
>>> list(out_main)
[5, 2, 7]
```

This has the advantage of lazily generating `in_main` and `out_main` from another lazily generated sequence. The only catch is that if you iterate through one before the other, `tee` has to cache a bunch of data until it's used by the other iterator. So this is really only useful if you iterate through them both at roughly the same time. Otherwise you might as well use auxiliary storage yourself.

There's also an interesting ternary operator-based solution. (You could squish this into a list comprehension, but that would be wrong.) I changed main_list into a set for O(1) lookup.

```
>>> main_set = set(main_list)
>>> in_main = []
>>> out_main = []
>>> for p in part_list:
...     (in_main if p in main_set else out_main).append(p)
... 
>>> in_main
[4, 1]
>>> out_main
[5, 2, 7]
```

There's also a fun `collections.defaultdict` approach:

```
>>> import collections
>>> in_out = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> for p in part_list:
...     in_out[p in main_list].append(p)
... 
>>> in_out
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {False: [5, 2, 7], True: [4, 1]})
```

Comment: +1 for the second solution but not sure about the itertools solution.

Comment: Seems like it is over-doing it, it would also involve zipping the final result and filtering the `None` out of the `in_main` and `out_main`.

Comment: @jamylak, ah, well that was just to show the contents of the generators. I'll rephrase...

Comment: I like the `defaultdict`, seems better than having two variables :D

Comment: in the defaultdict solution, how does it automagically create the 'False' list?

Comment: @dbv, every time through the for loop, `p in main_list` is evaluated and returns either `True` or `False`. Since those are hashable values, they can be used as keys in the dict. Then (in case you don't know about defaultdicts), when you try to access a key that doesn't exist, the defaultdict created by `defaultdict(func)` calls `func` (in this case, `list`), assigns the return value to that key, and returns it. Then the returned list's `append` method is called, and `p` is appended.

Comment: i use defaultdict a lot but didn't know that ... learn something new everyday.  both the ternary and default dict solutions work. many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

So long as you have no repeating data & order doesn't matter.

```
main_set = set([6, 3, 4, 0, 9, 1])
part_set = set([4, 5, 1, 2, 7])

out_main = part_set - main_set
in_main = part_set & main_set
```

Job done.

Comment: And as long as order doesn't matter.

Comment: variables want to be named as `main_set` and `part_set` :(

Answer (score 5):

If the order (within part_list) is important:

```
out_main = [p for p in part_list if p not in main_list]
in_main = [p for p in part_list if p in main_list]
```

otherwise:

```
out_main = list(set(part_list) - set(main_list))
in_main = list(set(part_list) & set(main_list))
```

Comment: I swear I wrote the sets answer first :P

Answer (score 0):

```
in_main = list(set(main_list) & set(part_list))
out_main = list(set(part_list) - set(in_main))
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by a list of predicates:

```
test_func = [part_list.__contains__, lambda x: not part_list.__contains__(x)]
# Basically, each of the predicates is a function that returns a True/False value     
# (or similar) according to a certain condition.
# Here, you wanted to test set intersection; but you could have more predicates.

print [filter(func, main_list) for func in test_func]
```

Then you have your "one-liner" but you have a bit of overhead work by maintaining a list of predicates

As said in other answers, you can speed up look up by using `set(main_list)` instead (not in the list comprehension of course, but before).

Comment: I am more than ok with downvotes, but just would you care to explain why? Thanks!

Comment: I upvoted you because I hate when people downvote without feedback.